How to give input shape to multi input model
I have trained a keras tensorflow multi target Sub-Classed model which takes two inputs, first input shape (None, 249, 194), second input shape (None, 123). I need to have the model.layers[0].input, however, the input has shape Multiple.
I have tried [this wrapper]
(How to set input shape of a trained model in Keras?) but this doesn't work for multiple inputs. When I give the inputs as a tuple, I get the error:
`Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value '(1, 249, 194)' with type '<class 'tuple'>'`

Do you know how I can give the input explicitly? I've tried to use keras.layers.Concatenate, but this doesn't work as the input shapes are not similar.

Hi, to define the input shape for a multi-input model, you should create an
Input() layer for each input. After defining the inputs, you can concatenate
them along the specified axis. Please refer to this gist to see how it works
in detail
